# How to set a value for even and odd rows?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table

```
db_name server_name approver
cube1   server1 
cube1   server2 
cube2   server3 
cube2   server4
```

I want to update approver column on every even row (assuming index starts at 0) and odd row with the following:

even (1st row): approver1
odd (2nd row): approver2

My ultimate goal is for the table to look like this

```
db_name server_name approver
cube1   server1 approver1
cube1   server2 approver2
cube2   server3 approver1
cube2   server4 approver2
```

I **don't** have a primary key/ID column, not planning to include one either

How can I achieve what I'm looking for starting from this statement?

```
UPDATE Table1
SET approvers = 'approver1'
GO
```

Comment: Which column or column combination defines the order?

Comment: And is `(db_name, server_name)` a key, hence unique? If not, which column or column combination is?

Comment: @stickybit no column defines the order. when i select i am able to get back all the rows similar ot the way i have the table in my post so im just relying on natural ordering. also, (db_name, server_name) are no keys. i dont have any primary key in my table

Comment: No order, no keys, no reliable chance of doing what you want.

Comment: @stickybit damn lol, what if i just ignore the db and server columns, and pretend its just approver column. cant i just set values based on even/odd row pattern?

Comment: Without an order, and a database table has no intrinsic order as it represents as relation, a special type of a set and sets have no order, there is no even or odd. The order the records are displayed when you query them once can be completely different the next time you query them and that is not a bug of the DBMS. So you cannot reliably do what you want without a column ord combination of columns defining the order.

Comment: There is no a such thing as 'Natural Ordering', the SQL server does not guarantee the order of returned resultset if you don't specify it with ORDER BY clause. You may have the result with same order for 1 million times, but it might be in different order next time.

Comment: @AdamYan yep, i know, but ive always been luck it seems to get the same order over and over

Comment: Why not add one more column like 'Created_Time' with default value sysdatetime() and created clusted index on it, that will save your life :)

Comment: @AdamYan because i would have to eventually update the same column in production, and that will be a tedious approval process so im tryna avoid any structural changes lol

Comment: I think by default it is the physical order on the harddrive, which could be relocated after a update/delete/restore DB/DB file patition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another option ...

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select *
      ,RN= Row_Number() over (Order By db_name,server_name) % 2
 From  YourTable
 )
 Update cte
    Set approver = case when RN=1 then 'ApproverX' else 'ApproverY' end
```

**The Updated Table**

```
db_name server_name approver
cube1   server1     ApproverX
cube1   server2     ApproverY
cube2   server3     ApproverX
cube2   server4     ApproverY
```

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by This assumes the partition/reset on db_name

Comment: ohhh i see what you mean. thats actually a neat way to think about it, instead of even/odd, its every new db_name...the only problem with that would be how would i be able to set the second db_name to approver2?

Comment: question: in regards to the beginning of your code ;with, does this really beging with semicolon ? i am not sure if its a continuation from something or the syntax is actually like that, which is first time i come accross something like this. also this one ,NewValue , starts with comma

Comment: question; would NewValue be in my case approver1? approver1 = concat

Comment: my question is, where in the sql statement is approver1 and approver2? i am confused how they are being inserted, i looked at fiddle and see that you create the table, with approver column value set to null, but i dont see how you end up inserting approver1 and approver2

Comment: so my question is, where are the approver1 / approver2 values in the statement, thats what im confused about lol. i dont see it anywhere in here: ;with cte as (
Select *
      ,NewValue = concat('approver', coalesce(NullIf(Row_Number() over (Partition By [db_name] Order By [server_name] ) % 2 ,0),2) )
 From YourTable
)
Update cte set Approver=NewValue

Comment: shouldnt it say something like SET approvers = 'approver1'

Comment: ohhhh thats how youre doing it, based on calculation. but what if ihave different values instead? suppose i want to add approverX, approver Y, approver Z...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195597/discussion-between-cataster-and-john-cappelletti).

Comment: hey can you join the chat please?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [modulo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but you need a id column here

Something like this (not tested yet). You need the same for "even"

```sql
-- get all ids from the odd numbers
With TableData  As
(
      SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS RowNumber
      FROM Table1
      where  (RowNumber, %  2) = 1 --odd
)
-- update the odd numbers with  approver1
UPDATE Table SET approvers = 'approver1'
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN TableData ON Table1.ID = TableData.ID
```

Comment: " but you need a id column here" so in my case, i cant use this method right?

Comment: Not out if the box indeed